# Why does the condition $|a_{n+1}-a_n|\le1/n$ not imply the sequence is Cauchy?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

While going through this condition I noticed that the sequence $a_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n$ satisfies
$|a_{n+1}-a_n|\le1/n$ $\forall n\in$ $\mathbb{N}$. However $a_n$ is not a Cauchy sequence, and with this I had established a counter-example for the condition. But ultimately I failed to understand why such a thing happened even though the difference of the terms were bounded by $1/n$, and $1/n$ is a sequence whose terms condense to a point as $n$ tends to $+\infty$(essentially the idea behind Cauchy Sequences).
Also how can I check if the following conditions imply "Cauchyness":
1.$|a_{n+1}-a_n|\le(n+1)^n/n^{3/2+n}$,
2.$|a_{n+1}-a_n|\le (n\log\ n)/e^n$

Comment: Recall that Cauchy-ness really means that $|a_m - a_n|$ is small for arbitrary (large) $m,n$. Since the harmonic series diverges, you cannot make $|a_m-a_n|$ small simply by taking $m$ larger and larger with $n$ fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cauchy sequences are about $|a_m-a_n|$ being arbitrarily small if $m$ and $n$ are both large enough

But in this case you have  $a_{2n}-a_n =\sum\limits_{j=n+1}^{2n}\frac1j \ge n \frac1{2n} = \frac12$, which does not get arbitrary small.